# Javascript after 7 seconds slide image

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, pack

http://jsfiddle.net/UWLsB/189/

I am trying to make the image slide to the left after 7 seconds, how come it's not working?

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="pack">
        <img id="pack" src="http://imgur.com/uGMzOGM.png">
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function FetchData() {
    $("#pack").css('margin-left', 0);
    $("#pack").css('margin-right', 0);
    $("#pack").animate({
        left: '-1000px'
    }, 'slow');
});
}
setTimeout(FetchData, 7000);
```

CSS:

```
#pack {
    margin: 5px auto;
    position:fixed;
}
#container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the same id for different elements. If you want to share css/javascript between them, better use a class.

Comment: @AlexSiri Thanks very much, I was wondering why it wasn't working on my full project. I just renamed the Div pack to packDiv. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have a syntax error.  The `});` line should be removed entirely:

http://jsfiddle.net/UWLsB/190/

I think you meant to use syntax that would have `}` and `)` on the same line or got it from some tutorial like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // .animate call stuff here
}, 7000);
```

By the way, you could do this purely with CSS using animations:

http://jsfiddle.net/UWLsB/192/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/UWLsB/191/

```
function FetchData() {
    $("#pack").css('margin-left', 0);
    $("#pack").css('margin-right', 0);
    $("#pack").animate({
        left: '-1000px'
    }, 'slow');
}
setTimeout(FetchData, 7000);
```

you can also  make the first two lines of the function into one like this

```
$("#pack").css({"margin-left": "0", "margin-right": "0"});
```